# What is the proper way to analyze and safe check jackson JsonNode?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to analyze and safety check data-sets that are assumed to use the same format. For example, all data-sets should look like this:

```
{
    "firstValue":0,
    "firstElement": {
        "secondValue":1,
        "array": [
            {
                "thirdValue": 2,
                "secondElement": {
                    "fourthValueOne": 3,
                    "fourthValueTwo": 4
                }
            }
            {
                "thirdValue": 5,
                "secondElement": {
                    "fourthValueOne": 6,
                    "fourthValueTwo": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }   
}
```

All fields are assumed to always exist - if some data isn't specified, the value of the respective field is simply "null", for example: all data-sets contains "secondValue", but it may be null. Another example: all data-sets contains "array", but the list may be empty. A third example: if a data-set contains an element in "array", the element contains "thirdValue" and "secondElement", whereas "secondElement" contains "fourthValueOne" and "fourthValueTwo".

In a nutshell, the code below should always work to retrieve all data in any data-set (consider it as pseudo code, not actual code):

```
JsonNode root = builtHere();
JsonNode firstValueNode = root.get("firstValue");
JsonNode firstElementNode = root.get("firstElement");

JsonNode secondValueNode = firstElementnode.get("secondValue");
JsonNode arrayNode = firstElementnode.get("array");

for (JsonNode arrayElement : arrayNode) {
    JsonNode thirdValueNode = arrayElement.get("thirdValue");
    JsonNode secondElementNode = arrayElement.get("secondElement");

    JsonNode fourthValueOne = secondElementNode.get("fourthValueOne");
    JsonNode fourthValueTwo = secondElementNode.get("fourthValueTwo");
}
```

This is of course a very simplified example. The real data-set I'm working with is much larger and more complex, with nested lists etc.

What I need to do is analyze all the data, meaning extracting all the data from the json tree and checking if the json tree actually follows the the data-set format (where e.g. "secondValue" always must exist.)

I could do what I do above in the example code to extract the data, and check if each field exist e.g. root.has("firstValue"), but it seems like a really ugly way to do it, especially when iterating through nested loops.

Any suggestions how this could be solved in a smarter way?

Other questions: how can I use JsonNode to get the path from some current JsonNode to root e.g. /firstElement/array/0/secondElement/fourthElementOne?

Comment: You probably can autogenerate some class with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and just deserialize your json to this class. If json is invalid, you get an exception